# Best way to notify user in asp.net webform

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I would like to know what is the best way to do a notification in asp.net.

For example I have a form in which the user will provide some data. He then click the save button which call the save methode in my code behind.

In the save method I need to query the database to know if another related object exist. If not I need to notify the user that he will have to create the related object. This does not prevent the user from saving the parent object.

So I would like to do a modal popup telling the user : Hey after Im done saving your change, you will have to open another form and create the child object.

So should I create another NotificationWebform where the user will be redirect after the sava to notify him. It seems to be a "lot" of effort for a little notification. The best thing for me would be something like an alert in javascript.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put a lable on the page and display your message in that label after saving the data successfully to the database.

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't exist let him simply save it. If it already exists then just display that information to the user. Forget the JS alert and the modal pop-up; what if JS is disabled? Either way, just create success and failure messages/panels and display the appropriate one.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, when I used Web Forms, I made all pages inherit from a custom class that extens Page class and inside this base Page class, I have 3 properties, one for SuccessMessage, ErrorMessage and NotificationMessage

Inside the Master Page, you can have 3 Labels and each one has a bootstrap css class according to its type, or maybe you can use toaster (https://github.com/CodeSeven), to show a nice popup like Outlook client.

In your button click event handler, you can simply set the NotificationMessage = "You have to blah blah blah ".

In the base Page class, you will check the value of each of these properties and if it is not empty then you will set the text of the corresponding Label and set Visible = true